# Subtraction between members of a list of double

Tags: vb.net, list, function

I'm creating a public function for 1D linear interpolation. I was asking if it could be possible to work with List of Double, instead of Double() because there arrays don't have fixed lenght, but it is parametric, depending on the number of rows inserted in a datagridview. I've tried to declare double() as list of double() but I'm receiving an error about subtraction between members - that seems to be not allowed. Here is the code:

```
Public Shared Function Interp1(ByVal xnative As Double(), ByVal ynative As Double(), ByVal xinterpol As Double()) As Double()
    Dim yinterpol As Double()
    For i = 1 To ynative.Length - 1
        For j = 0 To xnative.Length - 1
            If xinterpol(j) > xnative(i - 1) And xinterpol(j) < xnative(i) Then
                yinterpol(j) = (ynative(i - 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i + 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))) - (ynative(i + 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i - 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1)))
            Else i += 1
            End If
        Next
        If xinterpol(xinterpol.Length) > xnative(xnative.Length) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Where am I doing wrong? I can't understand where the mistake can be. Other thing I was asking is, if with the provided code, yinterpol is the result of my function, because that is what I need to have as result. Thanks in advance

---

**Edit:** Here is the version of my code using List of Double():

```
Public Shared Function Interp1(ByVal xnative As List(Of Double)(), ByVal ynative As List(Of Double)(), ByVal xinterpol As List(Of Double)()) As List(Of Double)()
    Dim yinterpol As New List(Of Double)()
    For i = 1 To ynative.Length - 1
        For j = 0 To xnative.Length - 1
            If xinterpol(j) > xnative(i - 1) And xinterpol(j) < xnative(i) Then
                yinterpol.add((ynative(i - 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i + 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))) - (ynative(i + 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i - 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))))
            Else i += 1
            End If
        Next
        If xinterpol(xinterpol.Length) > xnative(xnative.Length) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I'm having back the error BC30452: operators "-", ">" and "<" are not defined for List of Double

---

**Edit II:** What I have to do with this function is to rebuild two list of double that I'm gonna type in the application through a Datagridview.
What I need to have is:
[image: Starting and ending list of double]

To rebuild the starting List, I have to implement a 1D linear interpolation function, in which, with the values in the column x-ending (from 0 to 106 in the example), I can obtain the y-ending. I've updated my code with your corrections but I think that my code is missing something to do what is my aim. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: No, I mean, provide a calling code example with values. Eg `Interp2(New List(Of Double) From {1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.3}, New List(Of Double) From {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}, New List(Of Double) From {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5})`

Comment: Actually, don't worry; I think you already up-voted another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Re: The error you're receiving using arrays, you have a couple of issues here.

One is that you're not actually returning a value from the function.
Another is that you haven't initialized the `yinterpol` array with a size.

It's also good practice to declare the types of your indices rather than infer them (set `Option Explicit` *on*, `Option Infer` *off* and *always* set `Option Strict` *on*).

Try this:

```
Public Shared Function Interp1(ByVal xnative As Double(), ByVal ynative As Double(), ByVal xinterpol As Double()) As Double()
    Dim yinterpol(9) As Double '<- Initialize array length
    For i As Integer = 1 To ynative.Length - 1 '<- Declare type of i
        For j As Integer = 0 To xnative.Length - 1 '<- Declare type of j
            If xinterpol(j) > xnative(i - 1) AndAlso xinterpol(j) < xnative(i) Then
                yinterpol(j) = (ynative(i - 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i + 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))) - (ynative(i + 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i - 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1)))
            Else
                i += 1 '<- Don't modify outer loop index
            End If
        Next j
        If xinterpol(xinterpol.Length) > xnative(xnative.Length) Then Exit For
    Next i
    Return yinterpol '<- Return a value
End Function
```

I prefer `Lists` over `Arrays` personally. Let me know if you want that version posted. Some sample data for the call would be helpful.

**UPDATE**: You shouldn't change a loop variable directly. So `i += 1` within the "j" `For` is a bad idea. (In fact, I'm not even sure the changed value will persist in the outer "i" loop.)

**List Version**

You List example is using ARRAYs of `List(of Double)` on account of the trailing "()". Most of the other issues still apply, eg changing loop index, missing return value, etc.

```
Public Shared Function Interp1(ByVal xnative As List(Of Double), ByVal ynative As List(Of Double), ByVal xinterpol As List(Of Double)) As List(Of Double)
    Dim yinterpol As New List(Of Double)
    For i As Integer = 1 To ynative.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To xnative.Count - 1
            If xinterpol(j) > xnative(i - 1) AndAlso xinterpol(j) < xnative(i) Then
                yinterpol.Add((ynative(i - 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i + 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))) - (ynative(i + 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i - 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))))
            Else
                i += 1
            End If
        Next j
        If xinterpol(xinterpol.Count) > xnative(xnative.Count) Then Exit For
    Next i
    Return yinterpol
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to use Lists because I don't know the size of this vectors. Their lenght will be defined with a dedicated integer. The problem is that I'm receiving an error, if using lists, when doing subtractions and I can't understand why.

Comment: @telemaco10399 Can you post the List version of your code? And some sample data please. There should be no reason why Lists would cause any problems that Arrays don't.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code and the error.

Comment: @telemaco10399 I think you really need to check your code. You're passing and returning (tho you're still not actually returning anything!) an ARRAY of `List(of Double)`. It should be `xnative As List(Of Double)`, not `xnative As List(Of Double)()`.

Comment: @SteveCinq A small thing, but it would be better to use `AndAlso` instead of `And`.

Comment: @SteveCinq I've updated my code, in order to clarify what I need to do with this function.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Absolutely - changed. The code also needs validation, error handling and the like.

Comment: @SteveCinq While there's nothing wrong with explicitly declaring variable types, having Option Infer Off will be a nuisance when you want to use anonymous types in LINQ.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Agreed; when necessary, I turn _Infer_ off, but I lean toward not using anons if I can help it. Personal preference. (I'm not keen on `var` over explicitness in C# either.)

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters for your function look like arrays of lists considering the trailing `()`. This can be used when declaring a `New` list to indicate you are calling the constructor, although in vb.net it is not necessary (unlike C#). You are asking calling code to provide and arrays of lists.

The error you are getting is because `xinterpol(j)` is the list present at index j in the array of list. Obviously you can't convert a List(Of Double) to a Double.

`.Length` is not available for `List(Of T)`. You should use `.Count`

Your index `j` makes me a bit nervous. You are basing this on the `.Count` of `xnative` but applying it to `xinterpol`. What if `xnative` is longer than `xinerpol`? You are begging for an Index Out of Range exception.

I can't see why you want to possibly add a single item to `yinterpol` and then quit if the `.Count` of `xinterpol` is greater than the `.Count` of `xnative`

```
Public Shared Function Interp1(xnative As List(Of Double), ynative As List(Of Double), xinterpol As List(Of Double)) As List(Of Double)
    Dim yinterpol As New List(Of Double)
    For i = 1 To ynative.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To xnative.Count - 1
            If xinterpol(j) > xnative(i - 1) And xinterpol(j) < xnative(i) Then
                yinterpol.Add((ynative(i - 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i + 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))) - (ynative(i + 1) * (xinterpol(j) - xnative(i - 1)) / (xnative(i - 1) - xnative(i + 1))))
            Else i += 1
            End If
        Next
        If xinterpol(xinterpol.Count) > xnative(xnative.Count) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return yinterpol
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I've edited my question in order to clarify which is the aim I want to reach with this function.